# Genericx86-64 machine booting error Yocto

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto

Tried booting up my image that i created for genericx86-64 machine and i received this error during the booting process.

```
genericx86-64 user.info kernel: 001: blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sr0, sector 870188 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
genericx86-64 user.info kernel: 000: blk_update_request: I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 395901, async page read
INIT: Id "S0" respawning too fast: disabled for 5minutes
genericx86-64 user.warn kernel: 003: EXT4-fs warning (device loop0): ext4_dx_find_entry:1680: inode #575: lblock 6: comm rc: error -5 reading directory block
cant create directory /rootfs/media/sda1: read-only file system
```

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Your question is not about programming (so off-topic to this site). The error is in a late state of the kernel boot (so probably it is not about the kernel). Your kernel cannot read (and so execute `init`). Check how do you create initrd images and the boot options

Comment: You need to provide context for error messages. IOW show the lines/messages before (and after) the error message.